# Trouble Importing Docker Keys from Keyserver

Tags: apt

I was trying to install docker on my Linux machine and I encountered this failure.  I tried searching for keys online keyservers and did not find it.
Any suggestions?

```
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-keys 58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
[sudo] password for skumaran: 
Executing: /tmp/tmp.0Zg1ACSsNU/gpg.1.sh --keyserver
hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80
--recv-keys
58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem when I was on VirtualBox with NAT network on Mac.
I stumbled upon a Virtualbox Bug that mentioned this problem:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16084

I was able to work around this by switching to Bridged Networking Node for VirtualBox.